# NAudio WaveOut Device ID

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I need select waveout device, to play sound. But I cant do that.

```
void Initialize()
{
_WaveOut = new WaveOut();
var reader = new WaveFileReader(FileName);
_WaveOut.Init(new WaveChannel32(reader));
}
```

This function starts, then the form start. After this on my form, I select waveout device with combobox. Combobox is filles with this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < WaveOut.DeviceCount; i++)
{
     WaveOutCapabilities WOC = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(i);
     comboBox2.Items.Add(WOC.ProductName);

}
```

After this, I select my device.

```
int WaveOutDeviceId = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
```

And start Play function:

```
void Play()
{
_WaveOut.DeviceNumber = WaveOutDeviceId;
_WaveOut.Play();
}
```

But my sound always play on default device (With number = 0). If I do this for microphone, this code works correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you've called `Init` it's too late to change `DeviceId`. I suggest creating a new instance of `WaveOut` when you want to change device.